# ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: oracle-19c, tls-1.2, wallet

I have implemented oracle wallet using orapki utility following this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834638/how-to-change-protocol-for-oracle-database-connection-in-asp-net-core

However, when I try to connect from the App Server to the database using the TCPS Protocol on non-default port 1531, I am getting the following error :

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 23 10:30:23 2022
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-28759: failure to open file
Enter user-name:
```

Is it the database user that I am trying to connect as need the permission on the db server wallet files? Does it need permission on the entire wallet folder or something else? I found nothing in the trace folder

currently oracle user own the wallet folder:
/oracle/apps/product/19.3.0.0/db/owm/wallets/oracle

```
Database :
Oracle 19c on Linux 7

App Server :
Windows Server 2016 with Oracle Client 12.1
```

Comment: The OS user invoking SQL Plus (not the Oracle software owner) must be able to open the wallet.

Comment: @pmdba in my case how do I resolve this issue? I'm invoking sqlplus from the app server and the user myuser already exist in the database.

Comment: The OS user (not the database user) running SQL Plus on the app server must be able to open the wallet on the app server.

Comment: On the app server I actually provided the wrong folder name in the path for the wallet that I created in earlier attempt. After fixing that it resolved this issue but I am now facing with Fatal SSL Error which I am investigating.